# Gnuplot is not putting labels on all the tic marks

Tags: gnuplot

I'm doing a log plot of a short data file:

```
22.5 4.5
15.5 7.4
12.2 9.6
8.0 12.5
7.1 14
5.7 16.4
4.4 18.2
3.8 20.8
3.2 23.5
1.2 28.3
0.2 38.4
```

The commands I used so far are these:

```
plot "data.dat" using (($2)*0.01):(($1)*(10**(-5))):(0.005):(0.3*(10**(-5))) with xyerrorbars linestyle 7 title 'dados colhidos'
set logscale
set xrange [0.035:0.4]
set yrange [0.05*(10**(-5)):30*(10**(-5))]
set xtics 0.04,0.05,0.39
set ytics 0.1*(10**(-5)),5*(10**(-5)),30*(10**(-5))
set xtics nomirror
set ytics nomirror
set format x "%f"
set format y "%f"
replot
```

But in the plot only the first tic mark (of either the x and y axis) is labeled:

0.04 in the x-axis and 0.1*(10**(-5)) in the y-axis.

I would post a picture of the plot that I'm getting if I had enough reputation...

I already searched in some books about gnuplot and in the internet, but I didn't found any help.

What I want is the labels (numbers) to be at all the tic marks. Do you have any idea?

Thanks for reading!

I'm using version 4.6 patchlevel 5.

Comment: I think your script is not complete. You are talking about a log plot, but you have not logscale. Also, your `plot` command must be placed as last line in the script. Please update your script such that using `reset; load 'script.plt'` shows the error. If you cannot include an image then upload it somewhere, e.g. at http://imgur.com/ and share the link. Then someone with higher reputation can include it.

Comment: I edited the post: I was forgetting some lines... Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For logarithmic plots, the increment specified with `set xtics` and `set ytics` are multipliers. Also, for logarithmic plots you cannot use arbitrary tic labels, but the labels must be related to the base used for the logarithmic scale.

Consider the example

```
set logscale
set xrange [0.035:0.4]
set yrange [0.05*(10**(-5)):30*(10**(-5))]
set tics format "%f"
unset key

plot "data.dat" using ($2 *0.01):($1*1e-5):(0.005):(0.3e-5) with xyerrorbars ls 7
```

With the result

[image]

This looks good to me regarding the y-axis. For the x-axis you may want to try using a different base for the logscale. But if the result is better, you must decide yourself:

```
set logscale y
set logscale x 2
set mxtics 8
set xrange [0.035:0.4]
set yrange [0.05*(10**(-5)):30*(10**(-5))]
set tics nomirror format "%f"
unset key

plot "data.dat" using ($2 *0.01):($1*1e-5):(0.005):(0.3e-5) with xyerrorbars ls 7
```

[image]

Comment: Got it! This certainly helped me. I'm very grateful to you!